# How many classes do I have to apply to an element for it to have the same precedence as a single id?

Tags: css

For example, let's say I have

```
div#mydiv {... }
```

What is the smallest `N` such that the second line of

```
div#mydiv { ... }
div.class-1.class-2.class-3.....class-N { ... }
```

would override the first line?

Comment: here you have a Specifity Calculator http://specificity.keegan.st/ but an ID has always more value than 1000000000000........ classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such N. An ID will hold specificity precedence over any number of classes. See: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/.

Comment: As a side note, this might actually be hitting one of the actual use cases of `!important` in production: utility classes that make no sense if they can be overridden (such as `.bold { font-weight:bold !important; }`)

Comment: As a general rule, one should seek to climb the specificity ladder slowly before resorting to `!important`, which ultimately should be a last resort. There are exceptions, mainly utility classes, as mentioned by @abluejelly.